# $\operatorname{tr}(AB)$ in terms of $\operatorname{tr}(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have two symmetric and positive semi-definite matrices $A$ and $B$. I know $\operatorname{tr}(AB) \neq \operatorname{tr}(A)\cdot \operatorname{tr}(B)$.

Are there any ways to think of $\operatorname{tr}(AB)$ in terms of $\operatorname{tr}(A)$?

Comment: Not more than there are of thinking $ab+cd$ in terms of $a+c$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Choose any matrix $A_0$ and form 
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix} A_0&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Now, with $$B=\begin{bmatrix} I&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix},$$ you have $\operatorname{Tr}(AB)=\operatorname{Tr}(A)$. But if 
$$
B=\begin{bmatrix} 0&0\\0&I\end{bmatrix},
$$
now $\operatorname{Tr}(AB)=0$. Same $A$.

Comment: I have a follow up question, is it valid to say $tr(AB) \geq tr(A)$?

Comment: @lakdee Try $B=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\operatorname{Tr}(A^* B)$ is a scalar product you have Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. Since your matrices are symmetric (and I assume real) you have

$$
\left|\operatorname{Tr}(AB)\right|^2\le \operatorname{Tr}(A^2)\operatorname{Tr}(B^2)
$$